# How to expand UIScrollView during runtime using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am using `UIScrollView` with dynamically loaded data from JSON, and I display view created depending on data that I receive.

```
        var view = CustomView(frame: CGRectMake(5, scrollHeight, self.view.frame.width-10, 0), customClass: CustomClass)

        scrollView.addSubview(view)
        scrollHeight += view.frame.height + 25
        scrollView.contentSize.height += view.frame.height+25
```

but i have too many elements, and it lasts for too long to load all views, how can I load only 10 of them for example, and the rest must be loaded while scrolling the `UIScrollView`?
If I need to use some gesture recogniser to get my scroll event or something please write an example.

EDIT:

I implemented scrollViewDidScroll method but this way:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > (scrollView.contentSize.height - 500) {
            self.setViews(self.viewsArray)
    }
}
```

It works fine, but not smoothly, it takes time for load, and during that time app freezes for a moment, how can i achieve more smooth behaviour of adding elements in runtime?

Comment: are you using UITableView ??!

Comment: Initially just add only 10 items and in the scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method of UIScrollView verifying the scrollOffset and if it is greater than the  size of (view.frame.height + 25)*10 - scrollView.frame.size.height, then load the rest of the views only if it is not loaded

Comment: Can you write an answer with example about using this method please.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a nice way to solve this is by focussing on multithreading. You could do all the logic for your items in a background thread and then add them when they're ready on the main thread. So you will add one item at a time when they're ready... I think that would improve the behaviour, but you never know until you try :) 

I hope it helps!

(If you haven't worked with threads in iOS before, you should look into `dispatch`, e.g. `dispatch_async(queue: dispatch_queue_t, block: dispatch_block_t)`).

Comment: thank you, i'll try i think this is the right way)))